# Magento not seeing mcrypt in LAMP

Tags: 14.04, 13.10, php, lamp, magento

I am running Ubuntu 13.10 desktop and installed a lamp stack (Apache 2.4.6, and PHP Version 5.5.3-1ubuntu2), and I set up virtual hosts.  I also apt-get'ed php5-curl, and php5-mcrypt (no errors when installing)

I am trying to set up a Magento (1.8.0.0) development environment and the error I am getting is:

```
PHP extension "mcrypt" must be loaded.
```

How do I "load" mcrypt?

Comment: This very same issue still exists in 14.04.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with the mcrypt package in that it isn't included in the available mods after being installed.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446679/mcrypt-not-present-after-ubuntu-upgrade-to-13-10
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php-mcrypt/+bug/1241286

To fix, simply:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
sudo restart apache2
```

If the last command doesn't work, do `sudo service apache2 restart` instead.

Comment: This answer helped lead me in the right direction. I simply had to do:
`sudo php5enmod mcrypt`
`sudo service apache2 reload`
`sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: I have my mcrypt.ini file under /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini
when i try to do sudo ln -s it fails and say that file exist ... i dont see my mcrypt file on /etc/php5/conf.d/ or /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/

Comment: @GuillermoNahuelVarelli In Ubuntu 14.04 there is no need to create the link. Instead just do `sudo php5enmod mcrypt` and `sudo service apache2 restart`.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions is install php5-mcrypt module in and enable it.
Use the below command sequence.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
sudo php5enmod php5-mcrypt
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Follow the below url to install magento2 (M2) on ubuntu server.

http://gotechnies.com/install-magento2-ubuntu-server/